# How to enable JMX in Apache ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, message-queue, jmx

I am trying to enable JMX in ActiveMQ.
I have been following the instructions on the page: http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html

In the activemq.xml my broker tag is as follows:

```
broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="BROKER1" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" useJmx="true">
```

managementContext tag `createConnector="false"`

In the bin/activemq-admin I modified the value:

```
SUNJMX=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9876 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

I started the service: bin/activemq-admin start

The jmx options have been added to the activemq java process (ps -ef | grep java). 
I am able to see 9876 port with: netstat -a | grep 9876 -> tcp6 0 0 [::]:9876 [::]:* LISTEN

After that in JvisualVm, I added the remote vm's ip and I added the JMX port. 
I finally get a "Cannot connect to .... using service:jmx:rmi..." message.

What am I missing?

Thanks for the help,

Answer (score 0):

I updated the conf/activemq.xml, managementContext tag createConnector="true"

and then I modified the bin/activemq.xml value: ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9876 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX "

restarted activemq: bin/activemq restart

I was missing the rmi.server.hostname parameter